# Rails. postgres can't cast Array to string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, youtube

I'm getting **can't cast Array to string** error on production where I'm using postgres and in local I'm using mysql. While creating certain videos I'm getting error only on production.

In the below code videoid is nothing but id's of youtube videos which I'm getting from youtube

```
videoid = Video.parse_youtube(params[:video][:link]) if !params[:video].blank? and !params[:video][:link].blank?
              if videoid
            hash = video_info(videoid)
            if !hash["errors"]
              embed_code = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"#{hash['embed']}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
              @video = Video.new(:name=>hash["name"] , :embed_code=> embed_code, :link=> params[:video][:link], :youtube_id=> videoid, :current_views => hash["current_views"], :initial_views => hash["current_views"],:uploaded_date => hash["uploaded"],:category => hash["category"])
            else
              @video = Video.new
            end
          else
            @video = Video.new
          end
```

i am not getting where the issue is.. It is working in mysql but its not working in postgres.

Comment: Error message? Is this about MySQL, PostgreSQL, both? Is there anything in the server error logs? Serious lack of detail here.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the variables that you attempt to enter into a string variable in the database are actually arrays, or if hash["embed"] is an array, then you would get errors along this line.

My personal recommendation is to output the class of each variable that you're inserting just after the 'if !hash["errors"]' line. For example, 'puts hash["embeds"].class' would print out the class, and if it is Array, that could be your error.

You should be able to see the error pretty easily.